# Worst of both worlds?

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, model-theory

It's well known that $\mathsf{AC}$ implies the existence of non-measurable sets. And it's also true that, if all sets are measurable, then $|\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}| > |\mathbb{R}|$. But is there a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ where there are non-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $|\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}| > |\mathbb{R}|$ at the same time?

Comment: I think this is true in the "Barren Extension" [Henle, J. M.; Mathias, A. R. D.; Woodin, W. Hugh, Methods in mathematical logic, Proc. 6th Latin Amer. Symp., Caracas/Venez. 1983, Lect. Notes Math. 1130, 195-207 (1985).]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is also true over the Shelah's model of $\mathsf{ZF+DC}$ with "Every set of reals has the property of Baire" if we start from $\mathsf{ZFC}$ plus "$L$ does not have an inaccessible cardinal": On the one hand, Shelah proved that if every $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_3$ set is Lebesgue measurable, then $L$ has an inaccessible cardinal. So by the assumption, there must be a non-Lebesgue measurable set.

On the other hand, it is possible to prove $|\mathbb{R/Q}|>|\mathbb{R}|$ from that every set of reals has the property of Baire. It follows from slightly modifying Sierpinski's proof for $|\mathbb{R/Q}|>|\mathbb{R}|$ if every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable: Suppose that we have an injection $i\colon \mathbb{R/Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ then we can order $\mathbb{R/Q}$ by the order of $\mathbb{R}$. Now define
$$A = \{x\in\mathbb{R\setminus Q} \mid x+\mathbb{Q} < (-x)+\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
We claim that $A$ does not have the property of Baire: That is we claim that if $U$ is an open set, then $U\setminus A$ is not meager.

By taking a subinterval if necessary, we may assume that $U=(r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon)$ for some $r,\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Observe that for every rational $r$, $x\mapsto r-x$ maps $A$ to its relative complement in $\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$ bijectively. Thus if $U\setminus A = U\cap (r-A)$ is meager, then $U\cap A = r-(U\cap (r-A))$ is also meager. This implies $U\cap (\mathbb{R\setminus Q})=(U\cap A)\cup (U\cap (r-A))$ is also meager, a contradiction.

Comment: (Note: It might be possible to construct such a model with geometric set-theoretic tool: There might be a way to "force" a non-Lebesgue measurable set while preserving the property of Baire. I am unsure if it is really the case, but if it works, then the resulting model is compatible with large cardinals unlike the model I suggested.)

Comment: Do you mean rather $|R/Q|\nleq |R|$?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Yes, but $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves there is an injection from $2^\omega$ to $\mathbb{R/Q}$: For a given binary sequence $f$ consider a Liouville number $L_f=\sum_n f(n)/2^{n!}$. For two $f$ and $g$ that are not eventually the same, the difference $L_f-L_g$ is also a Liouville number so is irrational. We can find a set $\mathcal{C}$ of infinite binary sequences of size continuum whose elements are different infinitely many times, and the map $f\mapsto L_f+\mathbb{Q}$ is an injection from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathbb{R/Q}$.